# Excel Interop Efficiency get row number with value in a column

Tags: c#, excel

Currently I am using the below segement of code to get a row with a value int in the 3rd column.

```
        private int getRowByRDS(int id)
    {
        int bestfit = -1;
        Boolean foundOne = false;
        for (int i = 2; i < oSheet.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string val = getValueOfCell(i, 3);
            if (val == null)
                continue;

            int rds = int.Parse(val);
            if (rds == id)
            {
                bestfit = i;
                foundOne = true;
            }
            else
                if (foundOne)
                    return bestfit;
        }
        return bestfit;
    }
```

The issues is that this is pathetically show at large amount of rows.

Can someone suggest a better way of searching col 3 for a int and returning the last row # that it is in.

For Joe:

```
public void inputRowData(string[] data, int rds)
    {
        int bestRow = getRowByRDS_a(rds);
        string[] formatedData = formatOutput(bestRow, data);
        string val = getValueOfCell(bestRow, 6);
        if (val != null)
        {
            shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length);
            bestRow++;
        }
        else
            shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length - 1);
        // transform formated data into string[,]
        string[][] splitedData = formatedData.Select(s => s.Split('\t')).ToArray();
        var colCount = splitedData.Max(r => r.Length);
        var excelData = new string[splitedData.Length, colCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitedData.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < splitedData[i].Length; j++)
            {
                excelData[i, j] = splitedData[i][j];
            }
        }
        oSheet.get_Range("A" + bestRow.ToString()).Resize[splitedData.Length, colCount].Value = excelData;
        MainWindow.mainWindowDispacter.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => MainWindow.mainWindow.debugTextBox.AppendText("Done with " + rds + " input!" + Environment.NewLine)));
    }


    private void shiftRows(int from, int numberof)
    {
        from++;
        Range r = oXL.get_Range("A" + from.ToString(), "A" + from.ToString()).EntireRow;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberof; i++)
            r.Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

- Get a Range corresponding to the column you're interested in
- Get the UsedRange of the sheet you're interested in
- Get a Range that is the intersection of the above two ranges
- Get the value of this Range, which will be an array of values from the column you're interested in

You can then iterate through this array to find the value you want, then use its index to derive the row number.

The number of calls to the Excel is O(1) with the above method, as opposed to O(n) in your version.

Comment: Ok so, I got this far... Range colRange = oSheet.Columns[3] as Range; that's 1. Next Range used = oSheet.UsedRange;. Now I have no idea what to do lol

Comment: @YaWang - you're on the right track.  Next step would be to call the Application.Intersect method to get the intersection of the two ranges.  Good luck.

Comment: Got another efficiency issue. Need you opinion on the best way to shift cells down. I'll put my current code in edit above

Comment: I put up the code for inputing data and shifting rows give me you opinion please :D

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Find method of the Excel.Range object.  This method returns a Excel.Range object if a match is found or null.  Follow the first three steps that Joe described to create the search range.  If the Find method returns a valid Range, you can then use it's Row Property.

P.S.:  Sorry Joe I wanted to upvote your answer, but I am not allowed to do so yet.